# Then,what is the value of $P(0) + P(4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

A polynomial $P(x)$ with leading coefficient 1 of degree 4 is such that $P(\alpha)= 0$ and its roots are
$1, 2$ and $3$. Then,what is the value of $P(0) + P(4)$?

Comment: What is the expression of the polynomial, taking into account the conditions ? Please show your efforts.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The polynomial has expression $P(x)=1(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-\alpha)$.But what to do next?How to find the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Apply your formula as it is for $P(0)$ and $P(4)$ and add them.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanx,got it!

Comment: Good ! Simple, isn't it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Cheers!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Claude, I would like a second opinion (of a wise man). Who is right here (see the answers)?

Comment: @drhab. First I am not a wise man ! This being said, $\alpha$ could be any number (at least to me).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Should I take away my answer? I don't want to spread any confusion. Difficulty: it is accepted.

Comment: @drhab. Don't worry ! If I was given a dollar every time I wrote something not exactly right, I should be a millionaire. Trust the old man ! Edit your post and clarify (this is just a suggestion). Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomial is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-\beta)$, where $\beta$ is a constant. Substituting in $x=0$ and $x=4$ gives $$P(0)+P(4)=6\beta+6(4-\beta)=24.$$ We do not know what $\beta$ is: all we know is that $\alpha\in\{1,2,3,\beta\}$; but that information is irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

"It's roots are $1,2,3$ and $P(\alpha)=0$".

This justifies the conclusion that $\alpha\in \{1,2,3\}$. It is one of its roots.

---

**Addendum**:

Caution: it might be that @user2345215 is right is saying that I took the question too literally. If there is any confusion about that then let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Not in general, but *yes* if $P(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: It is good you made it ! $+1$ from the old (but not wise) man. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You know that
$$P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-\alpha)$$
Then $P(0)+P(4)=(-1)(-2)(-3)(-\alpha)+3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot(4-\alpha)=6\alpha+24-6\alpha=24$.

It should be noted that you only need to know that $1,2,3$ are roots of $P$ because then you can reduce it to a linear factor using polynomial division, so it always has a $4$th root $\alpha$.

Comment: @drhab You take the question too literally. I'm sure the original problem was: $P$ is a degree 4 polynomial with $1,2,3$ as it's roots. Find $P(0)+P(4)$. OP just made a confused mess out of it.

Comment: Even if you are right then I think this (including our comments) will be more educating than confusing for the OP. There is an essential difference in saying *roots of the polynomial are..* and *the roots of the polynomial are..*. This is a good lesson for the OP. Too literally in math, is that possible? :)

Comment: @drhab This answer works for $\alpha = 1,2,3$ without enumerating cases - so whichever interpretation of the question, the answer will be $24$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I agree on that. Nothing is wrong with this answer and I did not mean to say that something was wrong (sorry if that impression was made). I will delete my first comment on this.